# Animate / Reveal Content From Center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to make a circular div expand from the center of the div to reveal content within. The content within should not be affected by the resizing of the outer div.

See jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tim_m/22bnvLnn/3/

The problem with the example given above is that the circle is expanded from the top left rather than from the middle out. The content within is fine as is. Using transform: scale() would make the content small, but the point is to reveal rather than increase the size of the contents during the animation.

EDIT - Fabio's jsfiddle has led me to this, which is the closest I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/tim_m/wwonzr0u/2/. The only issue is that the content seems to swell slightly during the animation.

Here's my example code:

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}

.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle,.content {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}

.circle {    
    background: rgba( 99, 99, 99, 0.8 );
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
}

.circle.show {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this does what you want:

```
.circle {
    ...
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 150px; 
}

.circle.show {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;    
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    line-height: 100px;    
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100px;
}

.show .content {
    line-height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

In order to keep the circle in the same position, I've added a margin that decreases as the circle grows. The line-height and the width of the .content keeps the text centred as the element grows.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22bnvLnn/6/)

Comment: Sorry, maybe should've been more clear - the content should stay in the center, the circle expands around it. In your fiddle, it looks like it moves left and up during the animation.

Comment: I've updated the answer and the JSFiddle. Does that do what you want?

Comment: Close.. think of the circle and the word 'content' as totally stationary. The center of the circle is fixed, and the word does not move whatsoever on the page. The circle simply expands, keeping it's origin stationary. The content is still moving in your jsfiddle. :(

Comment: Try my latest update, I think it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You made me sweat with this one, but try changing your CSS to this one:

```
body {
    padding: 20px;
}
.button {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.circle, .content {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
.circle {
    background: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.8);
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 200px;
}
.circle.show {
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
    -moz-transform: scale(3);
    -o-transform: scale(3);
    -ms-transform: scale(3);
    transform: scale(3);
    z-index:0;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
    top:50%;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
}
.show .content {
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wwonzr0u/)

Comment: This is right in terms of the scaling of the circle, but the content should not change size. Think of it more like a clipping mask that widens, with the content remaining stationary and of the same size throughout the animation. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the problem is that you're adding scale(1) to the content when it should be scale(0.33), which keeps the content the same size as the beginning of the animation, but it does seems to swell and then reduce. See updated fiddle above, this is the closest to what I'm looking for.

Comment: ah, you can change the last line to `transform: scale(0.3); `(although `transform: scale(0.35);` works better, the theory is it should be 0.3, so test by yourself). However, there will be some movement since the transition will be calculating both scale and position at every framework

Comment: Right, exactly. That slight movement is the only issue with this solution.